# Automated test for typos

Tags: javascript, regex, unit-testing

**Introduction**

I have a dataset, say an array, of strings, something like this:

```
data = [
    'Lorem ipsum {{keyword}} sit amet',
    'Consectetur adipiscing {{different}} elit',
    'Pellentesque vel {{another}}^option^ placerat nibh {{yetAnother}}',
    ...
]
```

My application uses these strings and depending on circumstances replaces keywords {{...}} with something else.

I have Mocha tests to check if keywords are correct, the test checks them against a 'dictionary'. 
That is done with help of simple RegExp. Easy.

**Problem**

Now, I have problem and I have no idea how to approach it: I want to test if there are no typos like this: 
`{{keyword}` or `{keyword}}` or `{{kyword^option^` or any other combination... In this case my RegExp is helpless.

What would be most efficient and easy to maintain approach (the boundaries defining keywords may change in future or I may need to add some options)?

**Some more info**

The reason for such a test is that if the typo happens in the "declaration" (such as missing curly bracket) the app won't recognize this as a placeholder and won't act. It won't fail or log an error, it will just treat it as a normal text, therefore it's important to spot this early.

As this data is important part of the app and is produced manually and there are hundreds of them, so typos can (and will) happen therefore it makes sense to test it.

**So far...**

- my attempt to come with a RegExp to catch this failed
- reasonably effective and easy to implement solution: checking if number of {{ equals number of }} and check if there are no spaces on both sides of {{ or }}

Answer (score 0):

Part of this problem can be solved by fixing mismatched braces. I originally wrote this regex as an answer to a similar question:

```
[\{]+([^}]+)[}]+
```

You can just replace the match with `{{$1}}`.

This will work as long as there are one or more of `{` and `}` consecutively around the match.

---

I suggest using something other than regex for the rest of the problem (which involves dictionaries). Even a basic regex to perform that type of task will not be worthwhile, since the same amount of functionality would be easier to do with regular string operations.